# Which is better in this context – AdjP or NP as a subject complement?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, adjective-phrases, noun-phrases, subject-complement

When I need to describe myself (for instance in a letter to a potential employer or the like), should I use a NP headed by "person" as a subject complement, or just an AdjP? That is, which of the following would be better – (1) or (2)?

> 1. I am a driven [any number of additional adjectives] and enthusiastic person.

> 2. I am driven [any number of additional adjectives] and enthusiastic.

In my own language we tend to use the version with "person" a lot, but I have a feeling the opposite is true for English. Am I right about this, or are either option equally good?

Comment: Both expressions are very short. I think 1 is better than 2 in terms of the length. I'd say like "I am a type of person who always tries to achieve something when in the face of whatever challening work"

Comment: @Brandon Thanks for you comment! Yeah, I'm planning on adding a few other adjectives – my question here is solely concerned with whether the construction "I am a [Adj+Adj+Adj...] person" is as idiomatic as "I am [adj+adj+adj...]"